# Como bloquear o login em 2 dispositivos?

Tags: php, mysql, session, autenticação, cookies

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP onde o usuário pode manter-se conectado mesmo após encerrar a sessão, usando cookies. Porém, o usuário não pode manter-se conectado em 2 dispositivos simultaneamente.

Sendo mais específico, o que eu gostaria de saber é: Como eu faço para tornar inválida uma sessão (ou os cookies dessa outra sessão) quando o usuário fizer o acesso por um outro dispositivo diferente?

Comment: Você pode ter uma tabela secundária, e com base nisso, você registra o IdUsuario, o tempo que ele está logado e o status dele, se for o status 1, ele está logado em algum dispositivo e não pode se logar novamente, e se nao estiver, permite o login, antes de verificar o login e senha, faz a verificacao do status

Comment: @andré-baill No caso ele pode sim logar novamente, o sistema só precisa desautenticá-lo no primeiro dispositivo. Daí veio a dúvida.

Comment: Sim, se você fizer um SET status = 0, para deslogar, ao vc pode fazer um script que verifica o status, sempre que acessa algum arquivo e tals

Comment: Isso se torna complexo quando quiser deslogar em tempo real de um device quando fizer login num segundo device. Nesse caso terá que usar técnicas como long polling.

Answer (score -1):

Tendo em conta que a informação que não é suficiente para perceber o que já está feito como menciona e se me solicitassem para desenvolver um sistema dentro do que descreveu a minha opção ia claramente pela utilização de tokens `JWT`.

Para mais informações [JSON Web Token](https://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-json-web-token.html)

Já tenho várias implementações com este tipo de mecanismo e além de simples é muito bom para sistemas distribuídos ou com muitos acessos. Caso tenha alguma dificuldade diga.

Comment: O JWT não mitiga o acesso em múltiplos dispositivo.